# I have values from a text file that can only be counted if they are between 0 & 100, my code keeps skipping the first value

Tags: java, range, text-files, java.util.scanner

I want to make it where the values I count from a text file can only be between 0 and 100, it can't be less than 0 or more than 100. The values in the text file are separated by spaces and sometimes lines
ex: 57 59 38 60
49 24 60 39
I put in a if condition but it seems to be leaving out the first number even if that number is in the condition range, I assume it is because of my variable num, but I am not sure how to fix that.
Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExamStats {

    
    static final int A = 90,
                     B = 80,
                     C = 70,
                     D = 60;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        double minimumScore = 0;
        double maximumScore = 0;
        //total count of various grades
        int totalCount = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //asks for file's name
        System.out.print("Input File's name: " );
        String inputFile = input.nextLine();
        //reads the files data
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);

        int num = scanFile.nextInt();
    
    if(num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
        while(scanFile.hasNextInt()) {
        
        
            sum += scanFile.nextInt();
            totalCount++;   
        }
    }
        average = sum/totalCount;
        
        System.out.println("Number of scores: " + totalCount);
        System.out.printf("Average score: %.2f\n", average);
        scanFile.close();
```

Comment: Can you show the code with your if statement applied?

Comment: I edited the code(before while) - (it has // so I could see why it was breaking earlier.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input file?

Comment: @djm.im just added - forgot to when i first wrote this sorry!

Comment: The issue is that you have 'sum += scanFile.nextInt()` (which reads the next input), but since you didn't add num to your sum in your code your values are off and it skips the 1st number.

Comment: Amber, check @djm.im's answer.

Comment: Your approach was doing this: read the first value, check against the range, discard (this not counting) and now count the rest (regardless of the value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

```
while (scanFile.hasNextInt()) {
    int num = scanFile.nextInt();
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
        sum += num;
        totalCount++;
    }
}
```

---

And the possible reason for earlier exit is if the first line in a file is less than zero or greater than 100. In that case it will never enter inside the then-block ( `if(!(num < 0 && num > 100)){`.

---

For scanning multiple values in lines. You should scan line by line (String). Then split each line into an array of numbers (split by space `" "`). And finally, each array element from the arrays turn into a number.

```
while (scanFile.hasNextInt()) {
    String line = scanFile.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");

    for (String number : numbers) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);

        if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
            sum += num;
            totalCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you know how to make it where if there is a string in the file (like: "55 66 9 33 hi 39" ) it will skip it and continue the if statement? Or should I just make a new post about it?

Comment: Well, that's another question. From the top of my head something like this 
`String line = scanFile.nextLine();
String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
for (String number : numbers) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
}`
(It is not possible to better format in a comment.)

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. And please note that Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. It is not common practice to post "Thank you" (yes, that is nice and polite). And there is a better way - upvote and accepting an answer. More details here 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/where-should-i-say-thank-you-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Another reading suggestion:  How to ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work at all. I posted another question with more code to help explain the problem. I tried to use scanFile.skip(pattern);

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the condition inside the while loop.

This checks if the first number is inside the [0,100] range, and then executes some code:

```
int num = scanFile.nextInt();
if(!(num < 0 && num > 100)) {
  while(scanFile.hasNextInt()) {
    ...
    num = scanFile.nextInt();
  }
}
```

This checks if the current reading line is inside the [0,100] range, and only if it's true it executes some code:

```
while(scanFile.hasNextInt()) {
  int num = scanFile.nextInt();
  if(!(num < 0 && num > 100)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want to check if all numbers are inside that range just use a boolean inside the 'if' code.

Also, some files have '\n' at the end. I usually use `scanFile.readLine()` and then parse that to int:

```
while(scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(scanFile.readLine());
  if(!(num < 0 && num > 100)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention : each number in the file is separated by a space. So many are on the same line.  Also when I do what you suggest it either still skips the first value or it doesn't provide me with the correct value.